# Is it possible to use ipywidgets in a Dash app?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, plotly-dash, ipywidgets

I would like to use some dropdowns, combo-boxes and other complicated combinations of widgets from the `ipywidgets` library, which I have been developing in a jupyter notebook. However, I am forced to use plotly Dash for deployment. Is there a way I can display `ipywidgets` in a plotly Dash app without having to convert all of the individual widgets to their dash equivalents?

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget-app/ does this help?